# How can I make a rails exceptions more informative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I'm looking for a way to make my rails exception more informative. For example, it would be handy to have a few lines of code printed along with backtrace and local variables state.

The good examples of this kind of libraries is PHP's XDebug and FirePHP. But I can't find anything similar to those for ruby.

Also, I want to use it on my developer machine, so online-services are inapplicable.

**Update**
I found a project which is exactly what I'm looking for: [PrettyException](http://rubygems.org/gems/PrettyException) ([screenshot](http://freshmeat.net/screenshots/0d/aa/0daa3fd493b40f7bd3a8f54d6562b1e5_medium.png?1237054185)). Sadly, it hasn't been updated for 7 years.

Comment: Did you try debuger or http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails?

Comment: @Slawosz, yes, but I want my exceptions be as informative as possible, in order to optimize my workflow and put the use of debugger to minimum.

Comment: FWIW there's a [FirePHP plugin for Ruby/Rails](http://www.firephp.org/Wiki/Libraries/Ruby). You might also find [rails-footnotes](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes) useful. Finally, ruby-debug is extremely powerful and is discussed pretty thoroughly in the [Debugging Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-ruby-debug).

Comment: @Jordan, sadly, `FirePHP for Ruby` was abandoned two years ago. It also doesn't handle exceptions in the way original FirePHP does, i.e., doesn't include any context or code.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522816/core-dump-equivalent-for-the-rails-exception

Comment: @GregDan, it's relevant, but not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use something called [exception-notifier](http://rubygems.org/gems/exception_notification), which will mail me when an exception occurs, and will send me all the possible info I would need. The focus for this is to work in production, where it is invaluable when something has gone wrong. It can also work in development, if so desired.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I already use exception-notifier for production and it's really handy. But this question is about making your development environment more efficient.

Comment: i use Ruby debugger with Rails : ruby-debug gem for debug.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how/where the exceptions are thrown, using [Pry](http://pry.github.com/) at the exception site is awesome.

If they're *your* exceptions, adding pry is easy; just pry in the rescue (if it's not too far).

If it's the *framework's* exceptions, I'm not sure how deeply it can be injected into the process.

Instrumenting *your* classes would be (relatively) easy, but if you want something deeper, games will be need to be played. One hideous, but quasi-workable, would be to interrogate the stack trace and pull out file/line info that way, then spawn off an editor at any of those levels. "All" you'd need to do is wrap the world in something that knew what to look for. It feels evil, but tasty.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you trying to solve? The main problem with showing the code that raised the exception (and so goes for your gem) is that it's the last code executed. It's not per definition true at all that this code actually raised the problem. A stack trace can show you a lot more.

Using an application like Airbrakeapp (previously hoptoad) can help you catch errors in live applications. Ofcourse, this only works properly if you raise when you should :-)

Hope this puts things in perspective.

Comment: This should be in topic comment. At least for me, included code proved to be helpful. I get used to it in other languages&frameworks and looking for the same feature in Ruby&Rails.